# How do I subtract each list element by a value, using map?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a list  `'(1 2 3 4)`.

I want to subtract each value in the list by a value (for example 1).

I want to return the new list `'(0 1 2 3)`.

I'm using R5RS.

I've attempted to use `map` but failed.

I would rather use `map` over defining my own iterative or recursive algorithm.

Comment: What have you tried with `map`?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to `(- x value)` with each element `x`, map that:

```
(map (lambda (x) (- x value)) data)
```

or you could use a curried function:

```
(define (subtract y) (lambda (x) (- x y)))`

(map (subtract value) data)
```

Comment: this solution works for my purpose , though I don't fully understand how the parameter works for `subtract` , (subtract y x) takes two argument y x  ...why am I able to pass it the list 'data' ? (map (subtract value) data) , Is it because map breaks up the list into individual values

Comment: @localplutonium `subtract` only takes one argument and produces a function – `(subtract 42)` is `(lambda (x) (- x 42))`.

Comment: I haven't used scheme in a while ... Also did not study the language too in depth. Thanks I'll look more into it.